# Apple script to remove ._ files from USB drive

Tags: applescript

I need some help with an apple script that I can save on the computer so others can remove the ._ files from USB drives that are used for slide shows on TVs. I come from Linux so I pseudoed what I could.

```
usb_drives=$(ls /volumes/ | grep external) # intent
MyFlashDrive=$(prompt "Please select drive" usb_drives) # intent
dot_clean -m /Volumes/${MyFlashDrive} # mostly accurate
```

Answer (score 1):

The AppleScript version of this would be something like the following:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set ejactableDisks to get (displayed name of every disk whose ejectable is true)
    --name of every file of home folder whose name begins with "."
end tell
set targetDiskName to choose from list ejactableDisks
tell application "System Events"
    set targetDisk to first disk whose name is targetDiskName
    set dotUnderscoreFiles to every file of targetDisk whose name begins with "._"
    if (count of dotUnderscoreFiles) is greater than 0 then
        delete dotUnderscoreFiles
    end if
end tell
```

Of course, if you're more comfortable with unix you could write a bash routine and run it through `do shell script`, or just make an executable bash script.

Comment: I had to share this as well... chat.openai.com/chat:
```
tell application "Finder"
    set selectedDrive to choose folder with prompt "Please select the external USB drive:"
    set thePath to POSIX path of selectedDrive
end tell

do shell script "dot_clean " & thePath
```
Then it proceeds to describe how it works; i'd share but i'm character limited.